# How to add tailwindcss to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, tailwind-css

I want to add some code that contains `tailwindcss` classes. I tried to use `tailpress`, but it didn't work and my browser considers these classes as bootstrap and applies the styles accordingly.
But surprisingly, the same code works fine for `Twenty twenth-three` theme of wordpress even without the `tailpress` plugin.
**Note:** I don't have direct access to wordpress directory as it's saved on the server. I have access to wordpress dashboard (Theme File Editor) only.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and there are alternative solutions, for example [on this site](https://css-tricks.com/adding-tailwind-css-to-wordpress-themes/) there are other alternative ways, if I write here one by one it would be too long so I will just leave the source.

- https://css-tricks.com/adding-tailwind-css-to-wordpress-themes/

Comment: Please review the question again...